# how to display image in image view with back and front options

Tags: iphone

im new to iphone now im working animals enclyclopidea. procedure  is 6 image in 6 imageview when i click one image it comes full view and automaticaly go back in this we have to implement back and front options also.this is procedure.

so plz send me correct code for this animals enclyclopedia.

Thank u in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can invert your animations dictionary. If you have

```
[@"image1.png", @"image2.png", @"image3.png", nil];
```

then you programmatically set it to

```
[@"image3.png", @"image2.png", @"image1.png", nil];
```

and start animating again. And maybe you have to read the current image and set that as the first and calculate the others from this one.